# pydev will not install in Eclipse 3.72

Tags: eclipse, pydev

New user w/3.72 on Ubuntu. I'm trying to follow tutorials that say go into Help > Install New Software. Then add, then type in for location pydev.org/updates or try update-production-pydev.s3.amazonaws.com/pydev/updates/site.xml to get option to install pydev to eclipse.

I try but nothing happens after I hit OK in the entry/dialop add box. Is there something else to do - nothing happens, no checkboxes appear in the text area below, I see some options in the large text area?

I have a fast connection. Is there something I'm missing? Seems it should be easy. Nothing happens.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, and fixed it by unchecking "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" on the bottom of the Install window.

/Edit... I used **http://pydev.org/updates** for the location